# Change Material-UI ListItem children on hover/active

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Consider the following component structure of a side-bar navigation:

```
<ListItem button dense component={CustomNavLink} to="/dashboard">
    <ListItemIcon>
        <DashboardIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
</ListItem>
```

The task is to change the `ListItemIcon` and `ListItemText` appearance on hover or when the `CustomNavLink` becomes active.

> Note that `CustomNavLink` is an extended React Router's `NavLink` component
> that gets an `active` class applied to when it matches with the current route.

The following, somewhat hacky way achieves that (abridged and simplified for clarity) via `classes` property:

```
const styles =  {
    root: {
        ...
        '&.active, &:hover, &.active:hover': {
            '& path': {
                fill: 'red'
            },
            '& span': {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

(`classes` are then applied to the `ListItem` component)

This seems like an extremely lousy way of going about it, as the structure of the nested components leaks into the parent's styling... which is akin to doing this in the "old" CSS:

```
div:hover > ul > li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

**What is the idiomatic Material-UI way of solving this?**

> For reference, this is how it would be done in `styled-components`:
>
> ```
> const CustomNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
>     ...
>     &:hover {
>         ${ListItemIcon} {
>             path: {
>                 fill: red;
>             }
>         }
>
>         ${ListItemText} {
>             color: red;
>         }
>     }
> `;
> ```

Answer (score 17):

**Please Try following example for Change Material UI ListItem children on hover/active**

```
const wrapperStyles = {
  parent: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    '&:hover $child': {
      color: 'red'
    }

  },
  child: {
    fontSize: '2em',
    padding: 24
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a more complete answer, for instance how these styles would be injected into the jsx?

Answer (score 12):

Expanding answer by @Patel Charul. In case you want to change the style of multiple children on hover.

```
const wrapperStyles = {
  parent: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    '&:hover': {
      '& $child1': {
        color: 'red'
      },
      '& $child2': {
        color: 'blue'
      }
  },
  child1: {
    fontSize: '2em',
    padding: 24
  },
  child2: {
    fontSize: '4em',
    padding: 28
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it in **MUI v5**, first import the following components:

```
import ListItem, { listItemClasses } from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
```

Then define the your custom [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink), this `NavLink` will add the `active` className when it matches the current route:

```
function MyNavLink(props) {
  return <NavLink {...props} activeClassName="active" />;
}
```

Then in the `List` component, add the following styles to style the `ListItem` in active and hover state:

```
<List
  sx={{
    [`& .active, & .${listItemClasses.root}:hover`]: {
      color: "red",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      "& svg": {
        fill: "red"
      }
    }
  }}
>
  <ListItem component={MyNavLink} to="/" exact>
    <ListItemButton>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <InboxIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Home" />
    </ListItemButton>
  </ListItem>
  {/* other NavLink component */}
</List>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]